# Can an SVG have multiple begin or end triggers?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm kinda new to SVGs but I'd like to do this:

```
<set attributeName="y" to="4" begin="card.mouseover" end="card.mouseout" or "card.mousedown" />
```

so that it ends either on mouseout or mousedown.

Right now it is an SVG embedded in an HTML document and I can also use JavaScript if that works but that's about the extent of my knowledge...

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want [multiple begin or end values](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#BeginValueListSyntax) then separate them using semicolons i.e.

```
end="card.mouseout;card.mousedown"
```